# Python Django No such table page_article

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

у меня выходит ошибка No such table в Python Django хотя таблица существует

и в файле views.py пишет что

```
Class 'Article' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Article

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def news(request):
    lal = Article.objects.order_by("-date")[:20]
    return render(request, 'news.html', {"lal": lal})
```

и объясните как установить Pylint-django

Comment: [Вот тут ](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/#description) подробно описана установка pylint и сопутствующие проблемы

Comment: я уже решил проблему

Comment: Мы очень рады за вас. Но справедливости ради, надо бы запостить решение, дабы другие тоже могли решить подобную проблему